# Unable to find method 'io.realm.annotations.RealmClass.name'

Tags: java, android, gradle, realm

When I try to edit a written project that uses `Realm`, I getting the error below:

```
Unable to find method 'io.realm.annotations.RealmClass.name()Ljava/lang/String;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Knowing that this app was working on another device.

android version 3.2 and gradle is :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha08'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.4.1"
}

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Any help?

Comment: Any reason why you are using `3.3.0-alpha08` instead of something stable like `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`?

Comment: honestly i don't know the difference , i'm very bad with gradle .

Comment: when i edit it from 
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha08'
to 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
it become 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-rc02'
and the same error happened

Comment: You might want to try a clean rebuild, invalidate caches and restart